# Cannot borrow `x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I need to iterate and modify an element in a `for` loop but I also have to pass the `Vec` into the function that modifies it. Is there a better way to write this in Rust?

Minimum Reproducible Code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: Vec<Ex> = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..10 {
        x.push(Ex {});
    }

    for e in &mut x {
        e.do_stuff(&x)
    }
}

struct Ex {}
impl Ex {
    pub fn do_stuff(&mut self, x: &Vec<Ex>) {
        for _ in x {
            println!("Yay!")
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler message:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src\main.rs:8:20
  |
7 |     for e in &mut x {
  |              ------
  |              |
  |              mutable borrow occurs here
  |              mutable borrow later used here
8 |         e.do_stuff(&x)
  |                    ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

Comment: Maybe you have to rethink what you are trying to do in your algorithm. What are you actually trying to achieve? ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

Comment: Rust will not let you hold a shared (immutable) reference to the `Vec` while also having an exclusive (mutable) reference to an element within. Why do you have to pass in the whole `Vec`?

Comment: @NilsWerner I want to mutate the structs data dependent on the other stucts in the `Vec`.

Comment: @nottrue You're going to be in for some fun with that in rust.  I'd consider using a `Cell` or `RefCell`

Comment: Is there an other code structure that solves the issue?

Comment: @nottrue Why not pass a single `&mut` to the whole `Vec` and an index to the "current" element?

Comment: Or, you could also split the borrow with a `split_at_mut` and `split_first`, to get `&[T]`, `&mut T`, `&[T]`